Invalid escape sequences in Python 3.12 in a Docker image
I have the following code:
x = re.match("^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$", url)

It all works fine and runs under a Docker instance with python 3.11 installed.
The image has been upgraded to version 3.12 (it's a public GitLab repo) and now whenever we put any escape code in a string such as the above line we get errors such as, doesn't matter what the line, even \n:
Stderr: <string>:12621: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
<string>:12690: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
<string>:12699: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
<string>:12700: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'

Without access to the Docker instance, I presume there must be an issue with the Docker image and not something that has changed in Python. Where might the fault might lie, something I'm doing wrong, a change to Python 3.12+ or just a bad image creation?

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html -> https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#other-language-changes. You probably wanted a r"raw string", read https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

did you try use r before the string like x = re.match(r"^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$", url)

ah, so I've been doing it all wrong. Every example you see does not use r"
I expect this has caught a lot of people off guard? my problem is because via docker I don't see real error/warning.

thanks, most of my code was r"" without me realising. Stick it as an answer and get the kudos if you want.

hello, of anyone is still here... what constitutes a 'valid escape sequence', i.e. why does \n and \t work just fine but regex \d does not? I failed to find the documentation on valid sequences.
